# Why am i getting this error when i try to submit a form (Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFzCt.jpg)

why am i getting this error when i try to submit the contact form ?
And i get this issue only after hosting the website.
Website works fine in the local machine with contact form.

i changed the .env file according to the hosted db credentials.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>       SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cargills'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into
>   `contacts` (`name`, `address`, `phone`, `email`, `subject`,
>   `division`, `message`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sadsa,
>   dfsdf, asdsad, dsfsd@asdfsa, Customer Enquiry, Exports, sadsad,
>   2020-02-21 11:27:32, 2020-02-21 11:27:32))

Comment: remove cache from your laravel app

Comment: check db port in env file and do `composer dump-autoload` if you change anythhing

Comment: check this two command `php artisan tinker` and `config('database')` make sure your connection configured proper way.

Comment: Shared hosting or private one?

Comment: @SamuelBié  a private one

Comment: @Jareer Check the user privileges.

Comment: You have to dig out your sql server logs to see whether you have permission problem or app itself. But it seems to me that when you create your user you did not say anything to your mysql server that this user will have the access on the real network (in the internet). Check this out : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: This is the classic wrong db credentials issue. Just make sure that you are providing right DB credentials in your `.env` and after that just do `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons.

1. Your user and password is incorrect
2. User has not enough privileges to select or update that table
3. Incorrect hostname, sometimes changing `DB_HOST` to 127.0.0.1 solves that

Also make sure you don't have cached wrong/testing user and password
run

> php artisan:cache clear

Then run:

> php artisan config:cache

To cache new `.env` file

Hope this helps you

Comment: Did all the above changes, still i get the same error

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user

Comment: cache:clear will clear the cache but will not set the new credentials. So you will end up with an empty cache after this.

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:cache` to cache your .env again

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in your production you still try to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Put the right ip in your env file to your host, check the port and then in the production console run:
`php artisan config:cache` so laravel get's the right credentials from your .env file.